# Variable assignment inside bash script inside Jenkins pipline

Tags: bash, jenkins-pipeline

Inside a stage I'm trying to do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(ls)
echo "a is $(a)"
```

When I'm running the pipline I'm getting "line 3: a: command not found"

I used scripts inside pipelines before and didn't encounter this.

Answer (score 1):

Expand the variable `a` with `$a` or `${a}`.

```
echo "a is $a"
echo "a is ${a}"
```

`$(a)` is [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `${a}` here, `$(a)` is for a subshell.